# How to disable an Android button?

Tags: android, android-button

I have created a layout that contains two buttons, Next and Previous. In between the buttons I'm generating some dynamic views. So when I first launch the application I want to disable the "Previous" button since there wont be any previous views. I also want to disable the "Next" button when there are not more views to display. Is there anyway to disable the buttons?

[image: screen shot of sample layout]

Answer (score 922, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
myButton.setEnabled(false);
```

Update: Thanks to Gwen. Almost forgot that `android:clickable` can be set in your XML layout to determine whether a button can be clickable or not.

Comment: the equivalent is android:enabled in xml.

Comment: And where did you find that in the documentation? Can you link it here?

Comment: @Namratha it is working just for "Button" widgets, not for imageView as a button

Comment: Xamarin equivalent: myButton.Enabled = false;

Answer (score 58):

Yes it can be disabled  in XML
just using:

```
<Button
android:enabled="false"
/>
```

Comment: This is the real answer for xml.  All that nonsense of messing with clickable has nothing to do with how the button is drawn to make it look disabled.

Comment: I think people thought you can't do this because AS/IDEA code completion doesn't suggest `android:enabled` when you start to type it. (Even to this day.)

Comment: I tried it is not working, only from code `setEnabled` is working

Answer (score 52):

You can't enable it or disable it in your XML (since your layout is set at runtime), but you can set if it's clickable at the launch of the activity with [`android:clickable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:clickable).

Comment: 5 years of experience in Android and I get to know about this NOW! :/

Answer (score 46):

You just write a single line of code in your activity

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
btn.setEnabled(false);
```

When you want to enable the same button just write

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
btn.setEnabled(true);
```

Comment: That is **2** lines.  This is one. `((Button)findViewById(R.id.mybutton)).setEnabled(false);`

Comment: Try to understand the feelings Matt.. ;)

Answer (score 31):

In Java, once you have the reference of the button:

```
Button button = (Button) findviewById(R.id.button);
```

To enable/disable the button, you can use either:

```
button.setEnabled(false);
button.setEnabled(true);
```

Or:

```
button.setClickable(false);
button.setClickable(true);
```

Since you want to disable the button from the beginning, you can use *button.setEnabled(false);* in the onCreate method.
Otherwise, from XML, you can directly use:

```
android:clickable = "false"
```

So:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_text"
        android:clickable = "false" />
```

Comment: answered Dec 8 '10 at 7:08 Varun

Comment: @Poldie: Actually, if you read the two answers you will understand they are pretty similar but not equal.

Answer (score 10):

In my case,

```
myButton.setEnabled(false);
myButton.setEnabled(true);
```

is working fine and it is enabling and disabling the button as it should. But once the button state becomes disabled, it never goes back to the enabled state again, although it's clickable. I tried invalidating and refreshing the drawable state, but no luck.

```
myButton.invalidate();
myButton.refreshDrawableState();
```

If you or anyone having a similar issue, what works for me is setting the background drawable again. Works on any API Level.

```
myButton.setEnabled(true);
myButton.setBackgroundDrawable(activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.myButtonDrawable));
```

Answer (score 10):

In Kotlin, if you refer the Button View with id then, enable/disable button as like

**layout.xml**

```
<Button
   android:id="@+id/btn_start"
   android:layout_width="100dp"
   android:layout_height="50dp"
   android:text="@string/start"
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
```

**activity.kt**

```
  btn_start.isEnabled = true   //to enable button
  btn_start.isEnabled = false  //to disable button
```

Answer (score 7):

With Kotlin you can do,

```
// to disable clicks
myButton.isClickable = false 

// to disable button
myButton.isEnabled = false

// to enable clicks
myButton.isClickable = true 

// to enable button
myButton.isEnabled = true
```

Comment: // to enable button
myButton.isEnabled = false <----- should be true

Answer (score 4):

**WRONG WAY** IN LISTENER TO USE VARIABLE INSTEAD OF PARAMETER!!!

```
btnSend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        btnSend.setClickable(false);

    }
});
```

**RIGHT WAY:**

```
btnSend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        /** check given view  by assertion or cast as u wish */
        if(v instance of Button) {

            /** cast */
            Button button = (Button) v;

            /** we can perform some check up */
            if(button.getId() == EXPECTED_ID) {

                /** disable view */
                button.setEnabled(false)            
                button.setClickable(false); 
            }

        } else {

             /** you can for example find desired view by root view  */
             Button bt = (Button) v.getRootView().findViewById(R.id.btId);

             /*check for button */
             if(bt!=null) {

                 /** disable button view */
                 ...
             } else {
                 /** according to @jeroen-bollen remark
                   * we made assumption that we expected a view
                   * of type button here in other any case  
                   */
                  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong argument: " +
                         "View passed to method is not a Button type!");
             }
          }
       }
    });
```

EDIT: 
In reply to @jeroen-bollen

> ```
>  View.OnClickListener
> ```
>
> is **Interface definition** for a callback to be invoked when a view is clicked.
>
> with **method definition**
>
> ```
> void onClick(View v);
> ```

when the view is clicked the View class object makes callback to method onClick() sending as parameter itself, so null view parameter should not occur if it does it's an **Assertion Error** it could happen for example when View object class was destroyed in meanwhile (for example collected by GC) or method was tampered due to hack

little about **instanceof & null**

> JLS / 15.20.2. Type Comparison Operator instanceof
>
> At run time, the result of the instanceof operator is true
>       if the value of the RelationalExpression is not null
>       and the reference could be cast to the ReferenceType
>           without raising a ClassCastException.
>
> **Otherwise the result is false**.

---

three words from the Author

**IF U ASK WHY ?**

**MOSTLY TO AVOID NullPointerException**

Little more code will save your time on later bug tracking in your code & reduces the occurrence of abnomalies.

**consider following example:**

```
View.OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        btnSend.setClickable(false);

    }
});

btnSend.setOnClickListener(listener)
btnCancel.setOnClickListener(listener)
```

Comment: Seems like any time the else expression would get called, the code is already bugged. You were expecting a Button but something else was passed. You *should* throw an exception when `v` isn't a `Button`.

Comment: Not quite what I meant, but an improvement nonetheless.

Comment: @JeroenBollen eelaborate please :) ok i see only one thing not consistent it's exception message about "wrong view passed to method".Besides it's just an attempt to show how it should look like.

Comment: I meant that when the function itself receives null, it's already a bug and it should throw an exception.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to disable button add this line of code.

```
Button button = findViewById(R.id.button)
button.setEnabled(false);
```

And enable button , just add this line

```
 button.setEnabled(true);
```

**Happy coding :D**

Answer (score 4):

You  can disable a button from your xml but that won't be dynamic. Best way to disable button dynamically is.

```
myButton.setEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 3):

first in xml make the button as `android:clickable="false"`

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_send"
        android:clickable="false"/>
```

then in your code, inside `oncreate()` method set the button property as

```
btn.setClickable(true);
```

then inside the button click change the code into

```
btn.setClickable(false);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    btnSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_send);
    btnSend.setClickable(true);
    btnSend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            btnSend.setClickable(false);

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use setEnabled method in Java.

```
myButton.setEnabled(false);
```

And in Kotlin

```
myButton.enabled = false
```