# How can I keep the total number of people the user is talking to?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a mobile app where users can talk to each other. I am using firebase real time database in my application.  In the application, I keep and show the total number of people the users are talking to. My method is to send the uid of that user to the "Contact" table when each user presses the send message button in the chat. This method is very costly. Because every time I press the send message button, it sends data to firebase. Is there a better method?

```
ContactRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Contact");

private void SendMessage() {
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    final String messageText = messageınputtext.getText().toString();

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(messageText)){

    }
    else {
        String messagesenderref ="message/" + messageSenderID + "/" + messageReceiverID;
        String messagereceiverref ="message/" + messageReceiverID + "/" + messageSenderID;

        DatabaseReference usermessagekeyref = Rootref.child("message")
                .child(messageSenderID).child(messageReceiverID).push();
        String messagepushid = usermessagekeyref.getKey();


        Map messageTextBody = new HashMap();
        messageTextBody.put("message" , messageText);
        messageTextBody.put("time" , saveCurrentTime);
        messageTextBody.put("date" , saveCurrentDate);
        messageTextBody.put("type" , "text");
        messageTextBody.put("from" , messageSenderID);


        Map messageBodyDetails = new HashMap();
        messageBodyDetails.put(messagesenderref + "/" + messagepushid , messageTextBody);
        messageBodyDetails.put(messagereceiverref + "/" + messagepushid , messageTextBody);

        Rootref.updateChildren(messageBodyDetails).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()){

                }
                else {
                    String message = task.getException().getMessage();
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Error :" + message , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        Map messageTextBody3 = new HashMap();
        messageTextBody3.put("Contact", "1");
        ContactRef.child(messageSenderID).child(messageReceiverID).updateChildren(messageTextBody3).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()){
                }
            }
        });

        ContactRef.child(messageReceiverID).child(messageSenderID).updateChildren(messageTextBody3).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()){
                }
            }
        });
```

Contact list count:

```
ContactRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        countusercontact = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
        contactcount.setText(Integer.toString(countusercontact ));


    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Db:

[image]

Comment: the only one thing is  whenever you click on button it submits a data,  so you need to disable the  button after clicking once

Comment: check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838838/disable-button-on-click

Comment: @SalmanShaikh If I disable the button, how will the user send a message? When I press the send message button, it sends the data.

Comment: Disable button after clicking once

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: @AlexMamo the code is working. It's just too costly.

Comment: What do you mean too costly?

Comment: @AlexMamo  Because every time I press the send message button, it sends data to firebase.

Comment: This is Realtime Database's billing mechanism. Maybe, you should try using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore).