# Disable login button till form is filled android sdk

Tags: android, sdk

Hello all simple question how do you disable the submit button till to edittext are filled is it an if command or something ??

```
    b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login);  
    et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
    pass= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);

    if (et & pass == '  ') {

    }

    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Login.this, "", 
                    "Validating user...", true);
             new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        login();                          
                    }
                  }).start();               
        }
    });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384890/how-to-disable-an-android-button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you might want to do is use a [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) and in `onTextChanged()` check to see if each is empty. But you want to check the text not the `View` so instead of checking `et` and `pass`, you probably want to get the `String` in each.

```
String etString = et.getText().toString();
String passString = pass.getText().toString();
```

If they are not emty and `null`, plus any other checks you want such as length then

```
b.setEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this isn't what you're looking for, but the

`b.setEnabled(false);`

will disable the button for you, then you can enable it when you need it:

`b.setEnabled(true);`

Answer (score 0):

To make sure the username is not empty we get text from the `EditText` and `trim()` it to remove newlines,spaces and tabs from beginning and end of the string. Then we check whether the length is greater than 0. We make the same check for the password and then enable the button functionality using `setEnabled(true)`.

```
b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login);  
et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
pass= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
b.setEnabled(false); 
if (et.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0 && 
            pass.getText().toString().length() > 0){
    b.setEnabled(true);
}

b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Login.this, "", 
                "Validating user...", true);
         new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    login();                          
                }
              }).start();               
    }
});
```