# How to enable the button based on onclick in another button in android?

Tags: java, android

I have two buttons in my layout namely,

- buttonAddImage
- buttonLoadImage

Now my need is, I want to enable "buttonLoadImage" If user onclick "buttonAddImage" else "buttonLoadImage" always disabled.How to achieve that help me.

```
        final Button buttonAddImage = (Button)   findViewById(R.id.buttonAddPicture);
        final Button buttonLoadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLoadPicture);
        buttonAddImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            buttonLoadImage.setEnabled(true);
            Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            // Start the Intent
            startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);

        }

    });
```

Comment: What is the problem with above code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable an Android button?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384890/how-to-disable-an-android-button)

Comment: The above code does display the "buttonLoadImage" after onclick "buttonAddImage" that working fine..but i want to disable "buttonLoadImage" if user doesnot click "buttonAddImage".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the code for disabling the button outside onClick method

```
        final Button buttonAddImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAddPicture);
        final Button buttonLoadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLoadPicture);
        buttonLoadImage.setEnabled(false);
        buttonAddImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            buttonLoadImage.setEnabled(true);
            Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            // Start the Intent
            startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);

        }

    });
```

Comment: yes now it is working fine thanks for your response.

Comment: Ok. Then do upvote and select as the correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

try setting the listener of buttonLoadImage in onclick of buttonAddImage

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(this);
        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        // Start the Intent
        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
final Button buttonAddImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAddPicture);
final Button buttonLoadImage = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonLoadPicture);
buttonLoadImage.setEnabled(false);
buttonAddImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
    buttonLoadImage.setEnabled(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define varible in your class like this 
`private boolen ISCLICKED=false;`D
then

```
buttonAddImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        // Start the Intent
        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
       ISClLICKED=true

    }

});
```

now check button is clicked or not

```
    if(ISCLICKED==true){

buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            //do somththing

        }

    });
}else
{
Toast.maketext(contex,"Add image 1st",Toast.LENGHT_SHORT).show;
}
```