# Disable button on an Android app for a specific period of time

Tags: java, android, switch-statement

I'm building a login style application within android studio. As part of this I have created a rule that if the counter which monitors the number of invalid login attempts, gets to 0. I've currently got it that when the counter gets to 0, the login button is disabled. I was wondering if there is any way of disabling this button for a set period of time, rather than for infinity?

```
switch (counter) {
    case 0:
        b1.setEnabled(false);
    break;

    case 1:
         tx1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    break;

    case 2:
        tx1.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
    break;
}
```

Comment: You would also have to consider what happens when the orientation changes and when the user closes the app and restarts it. Does the counter reset, does the timer end early etc?

Comment: When the user restarts the app the counter is reset to 3. I don't mind that everything resets when the user refreshes the application, as long as while it is still open the button being disabled for a period of time works.

Comment: Anyone seeing this question also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384890/how-to-disable-an-android-button?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use following code. it will disabled button after 5 seconds when activity or fragment start when you put in OnCreate() method.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() 
    {
        public void run() 
        {
            b1.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }, 5000    //Specific time in milliseconds
);
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this! is this best place within the else statement?

Comment: after `b1.setEnabled(false);`, yeah