# How to disable view ( Button ) for specific time period (for example 5 seconds ) every time user click on button in android studio in kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout, android-timer

When user click on the button (button is home activity) he will intent to game activity in 30 sec to 1 min user may win or lose and come back to home activity and then button must get disabled for 3 min (with time countdown showing) after 3 min button gets enable again and process repeat.

Please help me, It is the last part of my college project.

Wish you a Good Day!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable button on an Android app for a specific period of time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35648797/disable-button-on-an-android-app-for-a-specific-period-of-time)

Answer (score 0):

Well a simple solution to that would be to use a countDownTimer.

```
val timer = object: CountDownTimer(20000, 1000) {
    override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {...}

    override fun onFinish() {...}
}
timer.start()
```

You would start the timer when the user comes from the game activity. Then you could save the remaining time whenever the `onPause` is called and start over the countdown timer when the `onResume` is called. When the remaining time reaches 0 then you will enable the button again. Lastly, you would need to save the remaining time in a `sharedpreference` so that when the app is closed that you would start from the remaining time.

Answer (score 0):

As far I understood your question. Correct me if I am wrong.

The app launches Home activity (button enabled)-> button click of Home Activity -> open game Activity -> when you come back from game activity -> home activity button should be disabled for 3 min (button disabled).

so you want the home activity button should be disabled when are you coming back from the Game activity right? If yes

```
mHomeActiviyButton.enabled = false
val intent = Intent(this, GameActivity::class.java)
startActivityForResult(intent) // as startActivity for result is deprecated use new  one but logic remains same


In-game activity :
val intent = Intent()
intent.putExtra("DisableFor3Minutes",3) // you can customize time
setResult(intent)
enter code here

override onActivityResult function 
In home activity :     
val time = intent.getString("DisableFor3Minutes")

Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
mHomeActButton.enabled = true          
}, time)
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to add any handler or time
you haveto disable button on Button `onClicks()` and enable button on onResume()
like :

```
 mHomeActiviyButton.enabled = false
    val intent = Intent(this, GameActivity::class.java)
    startActivityForResult(intent) 
    
     override fun onResume() {
            mHomeActiviyButton.enabled = enable
        }
```