# How to disable a button in onCreate method with if statment

Tags: java, android, android-layout, disabled-control, fragment-oncreateview

I have a problem, I want to disable a button in onCreate method, please share the way of disabling any button at runtime in onCreate method.

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_requests_interface);


  Intent intent = new Intent(this, AdminPopup.class);
    startActivity(intent);


    String fName = getIntent().getStringExtra("fName");
    TextView tfName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.fName);
    tfName.setText(fName);
    String vuEmail = getIntent().getStringExtra("VUEmail");
    TextView tEmail = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.vuEmail);
    tEmail.setText(vuEmail);

    EditText vuEmailTest = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.vuEmail);
    String email = vuEmailTest.getText().toString();
    String str = email.substring(0,2);
    if(str.equals("bc")){
        String str2 = email.substring(3,9);
        boolean digitsOnly = TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(str2);
        if (digitsOnly){
            Button accButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.accButton);

        }
    }
    else{
        Button accButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.accButton);

    }

}
```

Comment: Set it as disabled in your layout. So, when you'll add it through `setContentView()` you'll find it already disabled. By doing so, you won't need any extra code. Except that to re-enable it later.

Comment: you can disable it through xml using `enbale` attribute.

Comment: Check this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384890/how-to-disable-an-android-button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Button button =(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonid);
  button.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    Button accButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.accButton);
    accButton.setEnabled(false);
```

Note that in your posted code, you are setting the button with `findViewbyId()`, which should be `findViewById()` (the By needs to be capitalized).

Comment: Can I use if statement in onCreate method ? Because I have to take some checks and then have to disable the button

Comment: Sure. Or you can write something like `accButton.setEnabled(check1 && check2);`

Comment: Its just giving runtime error after putting if statments in it

Answer (score 1):

Use `android:enabled="false"` in xml or `accButton.setEnabled(false)` in code
Also, it's better to check is numeric by this method:

```
public static boolean isNumeric(String str) {
    try {
        double d = Double.parseDouble(str);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Can I use if statement in onCreate method ? Because I have to take some checks and then have to disable the button

Comment: @bs140200456AqsaAnum Yes, why not

Comment: I just putted if statment and now it is giving runtime error

Comment: @bs140200456AqsaAnum Include your if statement

Comment: Can I edit above coding and How, I will put my current code there

Comment: Edit your question or send it as comment here

Comment: I just edited my post. if statement in onCreate method.And after adding this statement it is giving error runtime

Comment: what is error said? is email always has more than 9 characters?

Comment: Error is application stopped working. And yes email has more than 9 chars

Comment: You can read error from log. If you are not sure about length of email, then check it before substring

Comment: let me check this

Comment: Edited my answer. use `isNumeric` method instead of `TextUtils.isDigitsOnly`

Comment: I think its not the problem with email lenght, after starting AdminPopup.class , current activity doesnot starts

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
b.setEnabled(false);
```