# Create an UnClickable and clickable button

Tags: android, button

Using android studio, How can I make 2 buttons name (submit) and (next page) but make the (next page) button unclickable. Then make it clickable after the (submit) button was clicked.

Comment: show code what you have done?

Comment: show some efforts

Comment: use button.setenable(true) in onclik of submit butoon.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable an Android button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384890/how-to-disable-an-android-button)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this

```
Button submit, next;
submit= (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
next= (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);    
next.setEnabled(false);

submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                      next.setEnabled(true);

                }

        });
```

Comment: You really really helped me out thanks alot...you had the best answer for me

Comment: Is it possible if you can show me how to hide an unclickable button.

Comment: Try to hide by using next.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Answer (score 1):

---

### You can use Clickable property as false and change it after clicking submit button.

---

```
Button submitButton, nextButton;
boolean b = false;

submitButton= findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
nextButton  =  findViewById(R.id.nextButton)

nextButton.setClickable(false);


submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                   nextButton.setClickable(true);

                }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

1. how can I make 2 buttons name (submit) and (next page) :- using xml create two buttons

> ```
> <Button
>             android:id="@+id/next_button"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:text="Next"
>             android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
>             android:textAllCaps="false"/>
> ```

2. But make the (nextpage) button unclickable :- In your MainActivity.java with

> ```
> Button next =(Button) findViewById(R.id.next_button);
> next.setEnabled(false);
> ```

3. Then make it clickable after the (submit) button was clicked :-

> ```
> btn_Submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>             @Override
>             public void onClick(View v) {
>                 next.setEnabled(true);
>             }
>         });
> ```

Hope this helps. No question is a bad question. Cheeers! Reply if any doubts.

Comment: Wow thank you it's broken down perfect ...you are amazing

Comment: Glad I could be of help!