# How to enable button in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-button

I want to create a button which is disabled. Only way to enable it if user inputs correct details and after the user clicks submit, if the details provided is correct, the button is enabled to go further.

Comment: by disabled as in its invisible or is it the same button as the submit button?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable an Android button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384890/how-to-disable-an-android-button)

Answer (score 1):

set this property on initializing the button in your class

```
button.setClickable(false); // by default it is disable
```

put this code in your submit button onClickListenser to check input validity  eg

```
if(validateUserInput()) //check for the validation of your logic in a fuction
button.setClickable(true);
else
button.setClickable(false);
```

> function validateUserInput

```
private boolean validateUserInput(){
//your logic here for validation
if(your check)
return true;
else
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use these lines where you need to make button disabled or enabled.

`button.isEnabled=false`
OR
`button.isEnabled=true`

Answer (score 0):

You can disable it on code with Button.setEnabled(false);
then later you you can turn it on when the submit button is pressed with Button.setEnabled(true);