# Prevent user spamming the button while the firebase inserting data to database so that the data won't be duplicated

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-button

I have this android application where the user fill up their food order and some other data, and then pressed the button so that the data will be inserted to the firebase DB and then the application will go to the menu activity again through intent.

but here's the problem, after pressing the button there will be some seconds where the user can still press the button again, so the data in the database can be duplicated. is there anyway to prevent this?

here's the insert code

```java
Date date = new Date();
String name = edtName.getText().toString();
String note = edtNote.getText().toString();
String tableNum = noMeja;
DBOrderDataModel order = new DBOrderDataModel(name, note, tableNum, date, orderList, totalharga);
order.setOnProcess(true);
ForinFirebase DBForin = new ForinFirebase();
    
DBForin.add(order)
       .addOnSuccessListener(suc -> {
            limitPress = 1;
            Toast.makeText(this, "Pesanan Anda Berhasil Ditambahkan", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(PesananActivity.this, Keterangan.class));
        }).addOnFailureListener(er -> {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Terjadi Kesalahan Dalam Memasukkan Pesananan Anda", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        });
```

Comment: Did you consider [disabling the button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384890/how-to-disable-an-android-button) once the user clicked it?

Comment: try to disable the button or show loading to prevent duplicate click.

Comment: i tried using it, inside addOnSuccessListener, but if spam it fast enough, the data still got duplicated

Comment: Have you tried Frank van Puffelen's solution? What's wrong with it?

Comment: i have fixed it, turns out i put  the disble button method in the wrong place
thanks for answering my question