# Can I turn off FORCE STOP button in AOSP source code

Tags: android, android-source

I can run an application that I developed by throwing the system/app folder. But I have a problem, since this application constantly communicates with the server, the application must not be closed. As in the example I gave in the photo, it cannot be disabled in my application, but it can be stopped with force stop. How can I prevent this?

[image: 1]

I was wondering if I could change the setting force stop button to work. If the user clicks the force stop button on my application, it does nothing. I did not understand exactly how force stop works, but I think the killproces process will kill the application, so I made such an addition, how do you think.

```java
private void killProcesses() {
    if (runningAppProcessInfo.get(i).processName.equals("com.interprobe.saganakmdm")) {
        return;
    }

    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

    for (int i=0; i< mApp.mEntries.size(); i++) {
        ProcStatsEntry ent = mApp.mEntries.get(i);
        for (int j=0; j<ent.mPackages.size(); j++) {
            am.forceStopPackage(ent.mPackages.get(j));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add bypass code in ActivityManagerService.forceStopPackage

Comment: https://ctxt.io/2/AABg3cQwFQ Can you tell me my friend. What should i do? Which code line add bypas? @Yong

Comment: My friend, I want the force stop button to be unclickable, just like the disable button. How can I do that @Yong

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384890/how-to-disable-an-android-button